# Retrieving data from GLSL vertex shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I have lots of transparent primitives I want to sort before drawing, but to get the Z coordinate, the sorting key, I have perform in software all the transformations performed by the vertex shader in hardware.

I thought I could optimize the process by retrieving the Z coordinate from the shader, and using it to sort the primitives in the next frame. Since the order of primitives is not expected to change drastically between frames, it shall provide fair enough ordering. So, I'd like to know how to get batch of Z coordinates back from the vertex shader? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Transform Feedback](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/transform_feedback.txt) to get data from the Vertex Shader output into a Buffer which you can later read, but i don't think this will gain you much, you should profile which solution is best (experimentally).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at each primitive individually you should sort based on connected meshes' bounding volumes. This kind of sorting comes more or less for free if you organize the geometry in a spatial subdivision structure like Kd or BSP tree. Then the sorting problem is reduced to implementing a traversal of the tree in the right direction -- basically it boils down to a depth first traversal with the branches traversed in a near←→far fashion.

Comment: I want to implement some culling algorithm such as BSP, but it is hard due to the particular geometry of this game: I use the 4 available vertex coordinates to simulate the space in the surface of 4-D hypersphere. I don't know how those known techniques can be used in such situation.

Comment: haha upvoted for awesomeness. (squared) Euclidian distance to the origin works regardless the dimension, this should probably be your sorting criterion. BTW, make sure you fully understand the implications of messing with the W component. It's there for a purpose.

Comment: AFAIK, W is there just to complete the 1x4 column matrix on which the 4x4 modelview matrix is applied. Since I am carefully handling my modelview matrix, and I've already projected 4-D to 3-D (and set W back to 1) before applying the projection matrix, everything should be ok. I intend on using Z after projection to sort, so we are back to 3 dimensions.